# Flutter. Как сканировать штрихкод без UI превью камеры

Tags: flutter, barcode, flutter-ui

Нашел библиотеки, которые хорошо распознают штрихкоды, но они открывают UI-превью вида с камеры.

Как можно реализовать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "Сканировать" включалась камера и сканировала штрихкоды?

При этом никакой UI-камеры отображать не надо. После как штрихкод будет распознан, его мне надо будет передать аргументом в другую функцию.

Comment: https://www.rightscan.ru/catalog/items/tsd/urovo/?PAGEN_1=2 тут есть железячный сканнер и железячная кнопка :) а вообще, мой разработчик говорит, что можно и не показывать. только оператору будет не удобно угадывать фокусировку камеры

Comment: @nörbörnën на android я писал реализацию, вполне себе в слепую очень быстро и удобно сканирует, может с дешевыми телефонами будет проблема. А учить IOS и потом поддерживать два приложения не очень охото :) А ТСДшки дорого и лишнее, надо то от телефона только штрихкод отсканировать. Рабочее приложение есть уже, и всем устраивает. Только надо еще IOS... вот и надеюсь что flutter поможет меньшими силами решить проблему.

Comment: ну, мы тем же мотивировались, переписывая андроидовское приложение на флаттер

Comment: @Евгений через [Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) перекрыть экран камеры.

Comment: @MiT я использую библиотеку https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_barcode_scanner. Во Flutter делаю только первые шаги, Stack посмотрю, но библиотека как я понял, сама открывает виджет(?), у меня нет ссылки на него, что бы скрыть

Comment: @Евгений да, похоже эта библиотека запускает нативнию view поверх вашего экрана. Вам нужно использовать такую, которая встраивается в дерево виджетов: [scan](https://pub.dev/packages/scan), [ai_barcode](https://pub.dev/packages/ai_barcode)